# VueJS can't build the project without fixing linting errors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Build Vue Project with out linting.

We had a VueJs Vuetify project. We decided to update package-json file to it's latest version.
After that update,

`npm run serve` or `npm run build` commands failed saying build failed with errors.
These errors seems like linting errors. How do I skip this linting thing and build the project?

Is linting compulsory for build the project?

Comment: You could remove the linter, change the rules, or fix the errors

Comment: To disable linter uninstall it or use disable directives which you can find in linter's docs

Comment: You can also disable/uinstal linters in vue ui, in section tasks -> lint or plugins

Comment: Linter is not necessary but is highly recommendable. I would suggest fixing those errors rather than removing the linter altogether. In case you want to remove, just remove the lint references from your package.json and run a `npm install` again.

Comment: How can you leave the linter but tell Vue.js to run when there are linting errors? I generally fix linting errors before a commit but don't want it to hinder develompent. it's quite annoying having to add a `;` before running my application when that's not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Before build you can fix linting error through below command.

npm run lint -- --fix